# transfer data in another gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with these columns: id,name,price,quantity,total. Also i have a button and checkbox in every row of gridview. When i check some rows i would like these rows with the button to transfer in another gridview.How can i do that?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">


        <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdValue" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="price" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderText="price" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="price" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="quantity" HeaderText="quantity" 
                SortExpression="quantity" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="total" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderText="total" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="total" />


        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Land]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
<div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working with data grids, I usually create a class which hold a template for my data, and then I create objects from this class and put in a list, then I can easily bind this list to any grid.

For example:

```
public class LandTemplate
{
  public property Id{get; set;}
  public property Name{get; set;}
  public property Price{get; set;}
  public property Quantity{get; set;}
  public property Total{get; set;}
}
```

Then in your method which in your case will be the click on check box event you can do that:

```
List<LandTemplate> landList = new List<LandTemplate>();
public void CheckBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // get data from the current grid row...

   LandTemplate land = new LandTemplate();
   land.Id= currentRow.Id;
   land.Name = currentRow.Name;
   ....

   landList.Add(land);

}

public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.gridView1.DataSource = landList;
       this.gridView1.DataBind();
}
```

But you will need to save the LandList in a viewstate or session to don't loose data inside after every page refresh.

I didn't check for syntax, but I hope you got the idea.

Comment: add then i must write something in button_click to transfer these data?

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look and tell me if something not clear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution.I am not sure if i know how to save the landlist in a viewstate...:-(

Comment: one more question.In button_Click the gridview1 is the gridview in which i want to send my data?

Comment: Yes, it should be the grid you want to send to it the data, while my solution is not complete but it should give you and idea how to solve.